# Offscreen rendering with OpenGL version 1.2

Tags: opengl

With new versions of OpenGL I can do offscreen rendering using FBO, and read pixels from FBO and then do what I want to do with the data.

How could I do the offscreen rendering with older versions of OpenGL (like OpenGL 1.2) which does not support FBOs?

Comment: Extensions? Why do you want to use something so archaic, anyway?

Comment: You're probably going to have to use the window manager to do this. So unless you really have to I'd recommend against it.

Comment: Unless you're also targeting ancient CPUs, a software renderer will be faster and less hassle than trying to render on an ancient GPU.

Comment: @user57368 Can you be more specific about software renderer? You mean someother rendering libraries ?

Comment: @ShaoboZi no, you can actually get a software rendered OpenGL context and unless you're also using an ancient OS, you would get a much higher version than 1.2

Comment: PBuffers were the mechanism of choice for off screen rendering before FBOs were introduced.

Comment: Offscreen rendering is not possible with OpenGL version 1.2, no workarounds are available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legacy (pre-FBO) mechanism for off-screen rendering in OpenGL are pbuffers. For example for Windows, they are defined in the [WGL_ARB_pbuffer extension](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_pbuffer.txt). They are also available on other platforms, like Mac, Android, etc.

Aside from the ancientness of pbuffers, there is a fundamental difference to FBOs: pbuffer support is an extension of the *window system interface* of OpenGL, while FBO support is a feature of OpenGL itself.

One corollary of this is that rendering to a pbuffer happens in a separate context. Where for a FBO, you simply create a new OpenGL framebuffer object, and render to it using regular OpenGL calls within the same context, this is different in the pbuffer case. There you set up a context to render to a 
off-screen surface instead of a window surface. The off-screen surface is then the primary framebuffer of this context, and you do all rendering to the pbuffer in this separate context.

That being said, please think twice before using pbuffers. FBO support, at least in an extension form, has been around for a long time. I have a hard time imagining writing new software that needs to run on hardware old enough to not support FBOs.

FBOs are superior to pbuffers in almost every possible way. The main benefits are that the can be used without platform specific APIs, and that they do not require additional contexts.

The only case supported by pbuffers that is not easily supported by FBOs is pure off-screen rendering where you do not want to create a window. For example, if you want to render images on a server that may not have a display, pbuffers are actually a useful mechanism.

Comment: New to OpenGL, so . The glGenFrameBuffers api is  availablesince OpenGL 3.0, that makes the FBO available  since v3.0 ,right?  So , before version 3.0. FBO are provided through extensions, while extensions may not available .Fallbacks are needed when FBO extensions missed. That's what I thought.  Anyway,I'll try both pbuffer and FBO  extension solutions.

Comment: That's correct. I believe there were multiple FBO extensions before FBOs became standard in 3.0. My understanding is that FBO functionality was around for quite a while before 3.0, but the ARB had problems finding consensus on how exactly a standard version should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the FBO *extension*. FBOs are a driver feature, not a hardware feature and even the oldest GPUs there are (and I'm talking no support for shaders, just plain old fixed function pipeline) can do FBOs. I've still got an old GeForce-2 (the one that came out 1998) in use (in an old computer I use for data archeology; it got ZIP drives, a parallel SCSI bus and so on), and even that one can do FBOs.

https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt